# Columns display as rows on window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a responsive web page using bootstrap.  It works as intended when the browser window is >= 50% of the screen size.  I have some column elements nested inside of a column element, which is nested inside a row element.  So, there are 3 children columns of each row, and then 4 children columns for each column.  The problem may be occurring because I have a column nested inside of a column, but if that were the case then wouldn't it display incorrectly when the browser is full screen, too?

When the window shrinks to less than 50% of the screen size, the most nested columns display as rows.  I don't understand why this is happening.

```
<div class="row foo" ng-repeat="foo in fooCtrl.foos">
                        <h4>{{foo.name}}</h4>
                        <div class="col-md-4 fuzz">
                            <h5>{{foo.type[0].fuzz}}</h5>
                            <!-- START BAR DISPLAY -->    
                                <div class="col-md-3 bar" ng-repeat="bar in barCtrl.bars">
                                    <h6>{{bar.name}}</h6>
                                </div>
                           <!-- END BAR DISPLAY -->
                        </div>
                       <!-- More columns -->
</div>
```

In simpler terms, the bars aren't being displayed as columns when the window size is < 50% of the screen.

Comment: You should get familiarized with the gridsystem: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: You're not using the Bootstrap grid correctly in the first place. You have elements between rows and columns, and you have nested columns without the required nested row element. I suggest you review the docs and try again. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The col-md-* bootstrap classes only apply at a media query breakpoint where the window width is greater than or equal to 992px. As others have stated, you will need to use col-xs-* as that is the default class used.

You can read more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. As a best practice, you would typically wrap the maximum number of columns that could constitute a row in a div with the class row; however, that may not be your specific problem in this case. In most cases this is the set of elements with the lowest number (n) (col-*-n) that add up to 12 if you are using the default grid settings.

Some examples using your `.bar` classed elements:

4 columns of `.bar` elements on all devices:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 bar">
```

3 columns of `.bar` elements on extra small devices up to medium devices (992px in width) at which point 4 columns will display:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 bar">
```

2 columns of `.bar` elements up to medium devices, then 4 columns per row:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 bar">
```

And finally 1 `.bar` element per row up to medium devices, then 4 columns per row:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 bar">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a div within the larger column with class row.  Then you need to know that if  you are going to subdivide the larger columns, the way bootstrap works is that you would have up to 12 subdivisions, but with a smaller col, something like col-sm-12.  But I am not too sure on all this.  I have read and reread those bootstrap grid descriptions, and I am still trying to make sense of them.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You've set the size only for md. You haven't set xs/sm/lg. 
The default breakpoints for bootstrap are 768px, 992px and 1200px.
I suppose you have a HD Monitor the md-breakpoint is about half the screensize and the view will swith to sm ignoring `col-md-x` and using `col-sm-x`

Note: If nothing else set also set `col-xs-12` to prevent weird behavior